# Umbraco custom document type with dropdown

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

In my db, I have a regular table , that not connect to all other umbraco tables.

For example "**Team Table**".

This table managed out from the umbraco.

I want add in umbraco pages data from this table.

For example in "About page" add data of "MANAGER X" - from team table.

and on "Career page" add data of "EMPLOYEE Y" = from team table.

How can I do it?

Thanks

Comment: Creat a custom Data Type, see http://umbraco.github.io/Belle/#/tutorials/CreatingAPropertyEditor

Answer (score 0):

In the Umbraco backend this can be achieved by using [Sql DropDown Picker from the nupickers package](https://our.umbraco.org/projects/backoffice-extensions/nupickers/)